# jquery username validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hello i am trying to code user validation script for my website but i something is not right cuz its not working properly

:my code 
jscript :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input[name*="username"]').keyup(validateuser);
});

function validateuser() {
    var username = $('input[name="username"]').val();

    if(username == ""){
        $('input[name="username"]').attr('id', 'invalid');
    } else {
        $('input[name="username"]').validate({
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $('input[name="username"]').attr('id', 'valid');
        }
    });
    }
}
```

and a html input form :

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}"><br>
```

so all this script have to do is to set a id to input if its valid or if its not and change border color to red or green , so at first if i clear the field and its empty i got red border but if i write something its still stays red and no changes at all , so probably the the second part of code are not working just not sure why , if someone could help me to solve this would be really nice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a complete example using only jQuery(no plugins):

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .valid {
            border: 5px solid green;
        }

        .invalid {
            border: 5px solid red;
        }
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {

            jQuery('#username').on('input', function () {

                $("#username").removeClass();

                var username = $(this).val();
                var isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(username);
                if (isValid)
                    $("#username").addClass("valid");
                else
                    $("#username").addClass("invalid");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" />
</body>
```

**EDIT:**

To validate based on regular expression and character length:

```
$(function () {

    jQuery('#username').on('input', function () {

        $("#username").removeClass();

        var username = $(this).val();
        var isValid = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/.test(username);
        var length = username.length;
        if (isValid && (length > 4) && (length < 20))
            $("#username").addClass("valid");
        else
            $("#username").addClass("invalid");
    });
});
```

Comment: its works but not as its should be as example you type in : username59 thats ok its valid , and if you tipe username59%%% its not valid but if u start everything with a symbols and winish with a word or number it still valid example : %%%&&^^^^^^&*username59 is valid

Comment: So then change your regular expression

Comment: The first Google search I did gave me the valid expression for alpha-numeric characters - /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*$/

Comment: i have tried this one already no resutl at all code dont work if i do this pattern  /^[a-zA-Z0-9]{4,20}*$/ or  /^[a-zA-Z0-9]*${4,20}/

Comment: yea but i want to add min 4 and max 20

Comment: i notice that lots of you sentence doent end with ; is that okay ? or it should be there ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using JQuery validation plugin, then you should note that the selector that you want to validate should not be an `input` tag, but a `form`, as stated here:

https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate

Correct me if I am wrong.

To validate the input after keyup, the following code may be helpful:

Replace this:

```
$('input[name="username"]').validate({
       submitHandler: function(form) {
           $('input[name="username"]').attr('id', 'valid');
}
```

With this one:

```
var regex = [A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20};
$(this).attr('id', regex.test($(this).val())?'valid':'invalid');
```

Comment: okay then how to validate input field then ? and i am not using any plugins as far as i know

Comment: No plugins? Then the validate method would not work!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onchange` event. It occurs when the value of an element has been changed. For radiobuttons and checkboxes, the onchange event occurs when the checked state has been changed. You just need to call the script function when the element is being changed.

Here's an example: (html)

```
<input type="text" name="username" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9\w]{4,20}" onchange="validateuser()">
```

Comment: there is no differents between my way , its the same result